Redirección con Laravel no funciona
Cuando ejecuto Stripe (pasarela de pago) tengo una funcion que me redirecciona a mi vista tras terminar con el pago, entonces llamo desde ajax en JavaScript y todo perfecto.
El problema viene cuando quiero hacer lo mismo pero sin pasar por Stripe, entonces hice otra función similar a la otra modificando las variables y procesos para que funcione.
Cuando se ejecuta todo en vez de redireccionar con el return redirect()->route('ticket'); me lo devuelve por el response del ajax y no hace nada.
Luego puedo ver claramente que la vista se ha cargado desde el network de google chrome pero no redirecciona, he probado a pasarle el redirect como json y ejecutar desde el JavaScript una window.href.location con la URL pero en este caso sí redirecciona pero no le llegan las variables a la ruta y por ende no ejecuta la función como debería.
Dejo las dos funciones la que sí funcionan (success y #pagar-carrito) y la que no (successEfectivo y #pagar-efectivo):
$('#pagar-carrito').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    showLoader("Generando ticket, un momento por favor.");

    var filas = $('.table.table-shopping-cart').find('tr');

    var datos = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < filas.length; i++) {
        const element = filas[i];

        let idProducto = $(element).find('td').last().find('input.id_producto').val();
        let cantidad = parseInt($(element).find('td').eq(0).find('.stepper_carrito').val());

        if (idProducto) {
            datos.push({ id: idProducto, cantidad: cantidad }); // Agregar solo si el ID del producto existe
        }
    }

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "/obtener/producto/single",
        data: JSON.stringify({ productos: datos }), // Enviar los productos como un array de objetos
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') // Añadir el token CSRF para la autenticación
        },
        success: function (respuesta) {
            console.log(respuesta); // Manejar la respuesta, que contendrá solo los productos válidos

            var stripe = Stripe(stripeKey);

            $.ajax({
                url: '/checkout-session',
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': csrfToken
                },
                data: JSON.stringify(respuesta),
                success: function (response) {
                    if (response && response.id) {
                        stripe.redirectToCheckout({ sessionId: response.id }).then(function (result) {
                            if (result.error) {
                                console.error(result.error.message);
                                toastr["error"]("Error: Se ha producido un error al procesar su solicitud. Por favor, intente nuevamente.");

                            }
                        });
                    } else {
                        console.error('No session ID received:', response);
                        alert('Error al obtener la sesión de Stripe.');
                        toastr["error"]("Error: Se ha producido un error al procesar su solicitud. Por favor, intente nuevamente.");
                    }
                    hideLoader();
                },
                error: function (error) {
                    toastr["error"]("Error: Se ha producido un error al procesar su solicitud. Por favor, intente nuevamente.");
                    console.error('Error:', error);
                    // alert('Se ha producido un error al procesar su solicitud. Por favor, intente nuevamente.');
                }

            });
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            console.error(xhr.responseText); // Manejar errores
        }
    });

});

// Funciones SweetAlert

$("#pagar-efectivo").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    //showLoader("Generando pedido, un momento por favor."); $('body').addClass('no-scroll');

    var filas = $('.table.table-shopping-cart').find('tr');

    var datos = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < filas.length; i++) {
        const element = filas[i];

        let idProducto = $(element).find('td').last().find('input.id_producto').val();
        let cantidad = parseInt($(element).find('td').eq(0).find('.stepper_carrito').val());

        if (idProducto) {
            datos.push({ id: idProducto, cantidad: cantidad }); // Agregar solo si el ID del producto existe
        }
    }
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "/obtener/producto/single",
        data: JSON.stringify({ productos: datos }), // Enviar los productos como un array de objetos
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') // Añadir el token CSRF para la autenticación
        },
        success: function (respuesta) {
            console.log(respuesta); // Manejar la respuesta, que contendrá solo los productos válidos
            $.ajax({
                url: '/checkout-session-efectivo',
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': csrfToken
                },
                data: JSON.stringify(respuesta),
                success: function (response) {
                    console.log(response);
                    if (response ) {
                        
                        
                    } else {
                        
                        alert('Error al obtener la sesión de Stripe.');
                        toastr["error"]("Error: Se ha producido un error al procesar su solicitud. Por favor, intente nuevamente.");
                    }
                    hideLoader();
                },
                error: function (error) {
                    toastr["error"]("Error: Se ha producido un error al procesar su solicitud. Por favor, intente nuevamente.");
                    console.error('Error:', error);
                    // alert('Se ha producido un error al procesar su solicitud. Por favor, intente nuevamente.');
                }

            });
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            console.error(xhr.responseText); // Manejar errores
        }
    });

});

Código PHP:
public function success(Request $request)
{
    $sessionId = $request->query('session_id');

    if (!$sessionId) {
        abort(404, 'No se proporcionó un ID de sesión válido.');
    }

    Stripe::setApiKey(env('STRIPE_SECRET'));
    //dd(Session::all());
    try {
        Session::forget('ticket_data');
        $session = StripeSession::retrieve($sessionId);
        $paymentIntentId = $session->payment_intent;
        $paymentIntent = \Stripe\PaymentIntent::retrieve($paymentIntentId);

        $lineItems = \Stripe\Checkout\Session::allLineItems($sessionId);

        $productos = array_map(function ($item) {
            $price = \Stripe\Price::retrieve($item->price->id);
            $product = \Stripe\Product::retrieve($price->product);

            return [
                'name' => $item->description,
                'quantity' => $item->quantity,
                'price' => $item->amount_total / 100,
                'currency' => $this->currencySymbol(strtoupper($item->currency)),
                'id' => $product->metadata['product_id']
            ];
        }, $lineItems->data);

        // Generar un nuevo idComanda para cada transacción
        $idComanda = date("dmYHis");
        Session::put('idcomanda', $idComanda);

        $carrito = Session::get('carrito', []);
        $retorno = "vacio";
        $productosConDetalle = []; // Array para almacenar cada $mergedData


        foreach ($carrito as $producto) {
            $currency = !empty($productos) ? $productos[0]['currency'] : 'EUR';
            $ingr = "";
            if ($producto->ingredientes != '') {
                $ingr = implode(',', $producto->ingredientes);
            }
            $requestData = [
                'idcomanda' => $idComanda,
                'idplato' => $producto->id,
                'nombreProducto' => $producto->nombre,
                'precio' => $producto->precio,
                'cantidadConsumido' => $producto->cantidad,
                'mesa' => Session::get('mesa') ?? '-1',
                'email_cliente' => $session->customer_details->email,
                'estado' => 'Pendiente',
                'sinIngredientes' => $ingr,
                'currency' => $currency,
                'activo' => 1
            ];

            unset($producto->id, $producto->nombre, $producto->cantidad, $producto->ingredientes, $producto->categoria);

            $mergedData = array_merge($requestData, (array)$producto);
            array_push($productosConDetalle, $mergedData); // Añadir $mergedData al array $productosConDetalle

            $retorno = $this->comanda->insertComanda($mergedData);
            //dd($mergedData,$requestData , (array)$producto, $retorno, gettype($producto),Session::all());
        }
        //dd($retorno);
        Session::forget('carrito');
        // Guardar en la sesión para usar en la vista del ticket
        Session::put('ticket_data', [
            'session' => $session,
            'paymentIntent' => $paymentIntent,
            'productos' => $productosConDetalle,
            'numeroticket' => $idComanda,
            'categorias' => $this->categorias_navbar
        ]);

        // Limpiar carrito de la sesión
        //

        // Redirigir a la función ticket
        return redirect()->route('ticket');
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        var_dump($e->getMessage());
    }
}
public function successEfectivo(Request $request)
{



    try {
        Session::forget('ticket_data');

        $carrito = Session::get("carrito", []);

        // Generar un nuevo idComanda para cada transacción
        $idComanda = date("dmYHis");
        Session::put('idcomanda', $idComanda);

        //dd($carrito);
        $requestData = [];
        foreach ($carrito as $producto) {
            $ingr = "";
            if ($producto->ingredientes != '') {
                $ingr = implode(',', $producto->ingredientes);
            }
            $comanda = [
                'idcomanda' => $idComanda,
                'idplato' => $producto->id,
                'nombreProducto' => $producto->nombre,
                'precio' => $producto->precio,
                'cantidadConsumido' => $producto->cantidad,
                'mesa' => Session::get('mesa') ?? '-1',
                'email_cliente' => "pago efectivo - sin email",
                'estado' => 'Pendiente',
                'sinIngredientes' => $ingr,
                'currency' => "€",
                'activo' => 1,
                'size' => $producto->size,
                'observaciones' => 'sin observaciones'
            ];
            array_push($requestData, $comanda);
        }
        $total = 0;

        foreach ($requestData as $cmd) {
            $total += $cmd['precio'] * $cmd['cantidadConsumido'];
            $retorno = $this->comanda->insertComanda($cmd);
        }
        //Session::forget('carrito');
        // Guardar en la sesión para usar en la vista del ticket
        Session::put('ticket_data', [
            'total' => $total,
            'productos' => $requestData,
            'numeroticket' => $idComanda,
            'categorias' => $this->categorias_navbar
        ]);
        return redirect()->route('ticket');

    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        var_dump($e->getMessage());
    }
}

// Nueva función ticket
public function ticket()
{
    try {
        if (!Session::has('ticket_data')) {
            return view('error', ['mensaje' => "la ultima sesion caducó", 'codigo' =>  500, 'cantidad_carrito' => CarritoController::getCantidadCarrito(), 'categorias' => $this->categorias_navbar]);
        }

        // Recuperar los datos de la sesión y eliminarlos para evitar duplicaciones
        $viewData = Session::get('ticket_data');
        $viewData["cantidad_carrito"] = CarritoController::getCantidadCarrito();

        //Session::forget('carrito');
        Session::forget('idcomanda'); // Borrar idComanda para futuras transacciones

        return view('ticket', $viewData);
    } catch (\Exception $th) {
        return view('error', ['mensaje' => $th->getMessage() ?? -1, 'codigo' => $th->getCode() ?? 500]);
    }
}

Archivos de ruta:
Route::post('/checkout-session', [CheckoutController::class, 'createCheckoutSession'])->name('checkout.session');
Route::post('/checkout-session-efectivo', [CheckoutController::class, 'successEfectivo']);
Route::get('/checkout-success', [CheckoutController::class, 'success'])->name('checkout.success');
Route::get('/checkout-cancel', [CheckoutController::class, 'cancel'])->name('checkout.cancel');
Route::get('/ticket', [CheckoutController::class, 'ticket'])->name('ticket');


En #pagar-efectivo hay un IF vacío, y no hay redirección a nada según lo que veo. El que es con stripe, puedes ver claramente que tiene la redirección ahí. En la función #pagar-carrito, hace stripe.redirectToCheckout(...)

@Excorpion si es que esa funcion de redireccion es propia de Stripe y hace una serie de pasos intermedios con su API que luego vuelve al success() y redirije, sin embargo no he puesto nada en el if vacio por que como digo en el comentario ya he probado a redirijir desde ahi y si lo hago las variables de la vista ticket no se envian y la funcion ticket() no se ejecuta bien por lo visto

Bueno pues la redirección la tienes que hacer en algún lado entonces, y dependiendo de donde, es como tienes que enviarla, si como JSON o no.

@Excorpion hasta ahi llego yo solo

El redirect se tiene que hacer en el controlador en la funcion successEfectivo si o si y tiene que funcionar desde el controlador si o si, sin pasar por JS

He leído que ya has probado el window.location.href e indicas que "no te llegan las variables a la ruta". ¿A qué variables de ruta te refieres? ¿Puedes poner el ejemplo de una URL con esas variables correctas y a cuál te manda mal?

nada chicos muchas gracias pero el problema de que no llegaban los datos al hacer una redireccion en el success del ajax era una configuracion del app.php de laravel que tenia hecha con la cache, la desahabilité y todo funciono perfectamente, muchas gracias por la ayuda.

El problema de que no funcionara por JS era que no le llegaban los datos cosa que ocurría por una configuración de la cache de laravel, la deshabilite y todo funciono perfectamente al hacer la redireccion por JS, en resumen, no se es que cacehaba o que no lo hacia y puse la configuración opuesta y todo funcionó.

Podrías intentar pasarle algún array como argumento:
redirect()->route('ticket', $ticket_data);

También podría ser con los corchetes:
redirect()->route('ticket', [$ticket_data]);


Lo he probado y nada sigue exactamente igual

@BorjaLorenzo Si te tira algún error o alguna advertencia, actualiza la pregunta con los detalles.

Indicas que

el redirect se tiene que hacer en el controlador en la funcion
successEfectivo si o si

por lo tanto tendrías que modificar el controlador, como una opciòn, en lugar de hacer un redireccioamiento directo en el controlador, devuelve un JSON que indique la URL a la que deseas redirigir:
public function successEfectivo(Request $request)
{
     $url = route('ticket');
    
    return response()->json([
        'success' => true,
        'redirect_url' => $url
    ]);
}


Una petición XHR/fetch no provoca la redirección de la página completa.
Para dar soporte a ese caso tienes dos opciones:

Que la respuesta agregue un campo que indique que queremos mover al usuario a otra URL.
Que el código JavaScript que recibe la respuesta busque en las cabeceras una posible redirección.

Para no tener que modificar el código del lado del servidor, puedes agregar este código a tu JavaScript para obtener el contenido de la cabecera Location haciendo uso de XHR.getResponseHeader() en el evento complete de tu petición $.ajax():
success: function (respuesta) {
    const location = respuesta.getResponseHeader('Location');
    if (location !== null) {
        window.location.href = location;
        return; /* Evitamos la ejecución del resto del código */
    }
    /* Código en caso de no recibir la redirección */
}


Justo acabo de ver que @jorgesys ♦ te ha respondido con la primera opción (es la más versátil). Espero que me respondas al comentario de la pregunta para poder ayudarte con el problema subyacente que te hace perder las variables al redirigir a la siguiente ruta.
